# How shared hosted web servers deal with spam (flood) attacks?

Tags: web-server, spam, flooding

I want to know how shared webhosting or other types of it deal with Spam issues.

Example: stop serving the website for a period of time, and how much is it? ...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, hosting companies suspend the web site until the end of the attack.

The problem is that everyone will see something like "The account is suspended" message.

Also, this may happen when your web site receives a sudden spike of traffic with
many thousands of people coming to the web site and just crushing other web sites
hosted on the same physical server.